# How to add a responsive game to my website?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to insert any game from http://www.miniclip.com/webmasters/8-ball-pool-multiplayer/en/ to my website but when i do and try to make the screen smaller is not responsive. Is there any way to make it with bootstrap or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, choose full width on the link that you have sent!

I have created an example [here](http://codepen.io/panayiotisgeorgiou/pen/oxagea)

```css
.container {
  background: #e3e3e3;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
h1, h4 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
h1 i {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1>Bootstrap 3 Responsive video Embeds <i class="fa fa-heart"></i></h1>
<h4>Check out more <a href="http://panayiotisgeorgiou.net">www.panayiotisgeorgiou.net</a> for more awesome web dev things</h4>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">

      <h2>16:9 Responsive Aspect Ratio</h2>
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/JYv7Ibml4ro"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">


      <h2>4:3 Responsive Aspect Ratio</h2>
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/JYv7Ibml4ro"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h2>Miniclip Embed</h2>
    <!-- Place this code where you'd like the game to appear -->
<div class="miniclip-game-embed" data-game-name="8-ball-pool-multiplayer" data-theme="0" data-width="100%" data-height="560" data-language="en"><a href="http://www.miniclip.com/games/8-ball-pool-multiplayer/">Play 8 Ball Pool</a></div>
<p style="text-align:center;"><a href="http://www.miniclip.com/games/8-ball-pool-multiplayer/" target="_blank">Play 8 Ball Pool</a> / More <a href="http://www.miniclip.com/games/genre-3/" target="_blank">Sports games</a></p>

<!-- Insert this code before your </body> tag -->
<script src="//static.miniclipcdn.com/js/game-embed.js"></script>
  </div>
</div>
```

, have a look and let me know.

Comment: Thank you! It work's! I tried all day to find a way to do this.